# Finding a word in dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, search, data-structures

I have a small Java project of building a dictionary at school.

It is very simple at the moment, here is Word class.

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
    private String word_target; 
    private String word_explain;
    
    /*Getter and setter methods.*/

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {...}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word otherWord) {
        return this.word_target.compareTo(otherWord.word_target);
    }
}
```

and Dictionary class.

```
public class Dictionary {
    protected static TreeSet<Word> words = new TreeSet<>();
}
```

My question is: If I have a string input which is a word and I have to find its meaning, how can I do this with a TreeSet of user-defined object (in my case it is Word)? Or what is the best searching algorithm in my case?

I try to use TreeSet because it will automatically sort my input data from keyboard, which is very convenience when I show all words in my dictionary.

Comment: The set has contains method, check the javadocs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: In this simple scenario, maybe try using a `TreeMap` instead of a `TreeSet`? Then you can use a `String` as key.

Comment: I suggest you use `TreeMap<String, String>` where `word_target` as key and `word_explain` as value then you can easily get the data from map using word and data is sorted also by word.

Comment: `TreeSet` already use the best searching algorithm which runs in O(log(n))

Comment: @Omid.N Problem is OP wants to find by `word_target` not by Word, so how to use contains method ?  A way can be to create Word instance without word_explain  and if hashcode and compare properly defined search by it. But that will be very bad structure in a sense.

Comment: @Rono Okay I think in this simple scenerio, TreeMap is a better choice. But it is just the beginning of my project. Later I have to add many more functions (include graphic using Swing, ...) such as: What type of that word, pronouciation, word sounds, ... I think there will be a lot of properties in Word class, not just word_target and its explaination, so TreeMap would not be a proper datatype right? Sorry for my bad expression and English.

Comment: You can use `TreeMap<String, WordDetails>` where `WordDetails` class for store details

Comment: @Rono Okay! Thanks to you, I tried TreeMap and rightnow it works very well! In the following versions I will try to use TreeMap again, thank you so much :D